# Do we know who owned the lightsabers that The Path had?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

In episode 5 of *Obi-Wan Kenobi* we land at the Jabiim and the headquarters of The Path. There's a bit of downtime and Obi-Wan has a look about. He notices some Aurebesh writing on the wall with Jedi names and various light side related quotes. However, more notably there are boxes of belongings of Jedi there, cloaks and lightsabers.

[image: Close up of the 8 lightsabers on the top of a box]

Do we know who owned any of the lightsabers here? Obi-Wan also picks one of them up so that might be more important to him than some of the others; in a previous episode on Mapuzo Obi-Wan had seen writing on a wall of a Jedi he knew and said their name so perhaps it was theirs.

Comment: It would be interesting if any of these appear in "[Star Wars: The Lightsaber Collection](https://insighteditions.com/collections/star-wars/products/star-wars-the-lightsaber-collection)".

Comment: Presumably, all that remains of General Grievous's Fine Collection (TM).